# Sine curve on graph - SQL

Tags: sql, math

Im trying to create a easy sine curv in SQL which alternates between the values (0-23).

I have the following variables: x, which is the current offset. y which is the destinated offset, and z which is my max value(23).

Anyone that could help me with the expression? Have googled and read about it, but havent got it to work yet..

Would be greatful for any answers..

Best Regards,
Tom

Comment: post your attempt. This isn't a free work exchange!

Comment: could you explain your expected result in more detail?

Comment: ...and could you explain why you're trying to do this in SQL?

Comment: And im not telling anyone to do my work! Im just asking them to help me so I can learn how the sine curv works! The expression whould be fairly simple.. Just me who's not getting it to work..

I want to add some testdata to a linear graph. And I want the testdata to be in sine form, alternating between 0 and 23, with alternation on every 5th. Meaning, if it would start on 5, the second would be 10, the third, 15, the fourth 20, the fifth, 25.. And so on. Elevating down to 0.

Comment: This is perfectly valid and useful question. I myself have done it many times to model data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need some kind of a dummy rowset to do this.

In `Oracle`:

```
SELECT  level - 1, SIN((level - 1) * 3.141592653 / 12)
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY
        level <= 24
```

In `SQL Server 2005+`:

```
WITH    rows AS
        (
        SELECT  0 AS level
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  level + 1
        FROM    rows
        WHERE   level <= 23
        )
SELECT  level, SIN((level) * 3.141592653 / 12)
FROM    rows
```

In `PostgreSQL`:

```
SELECT  level, SIN(level * 3.141592653 / 12)
FROM    generate_series(0, 23) level
```

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  level, SIN(level * 3.141592653 / 12)
FROM    (
        SELECT  0 AS level
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1 AS level
        UNION ALL
        …
        /*
        Yes, you need to repeat it 24 times.

        Everyone who reads it: please call MySQL and ask them
        to implement generate_series.

        Thanks.
        */
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  23 AS level
        ) q
```